# How to set default global values for angular CLI

Tags: angular-cli

Everytime I make a new project, I want use these options:

```
ng new projectname --styles=scss --routing=true --skipTests=true
```

I just want these to be the defaults everytime I make a new project. The angular documentation makes this impossible to figure out. I even tried editing the node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json file and manually setting these defaults to true. This didn't work

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowleadge, you cannot alter the `angular-cli` default settings.
At best, you would need to clone the original repo and make extensive changes to match your needs.

However, you can solve the issue using an `alias` or a `function`.
You would need to check which type of terminal you use, `bash`, `Zshell`, `PowerShell` and see how to create an `alias` or a `function` for it.

This would ensure that you would only need to pass the new project name and the remaining options would appear by default, hidden by `alias` or `function`.

This is not a hard thing to do and should solve your issue.

Kind regards.